# Random minutes in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, c#-2.0

Ho do I go about adding random minutes to column in dataset, here is my code:

```
protected void btnUpdateTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 


    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
       ///check if column[logout] is null or empty, fill it
       if(dr.IsNull("logout_time"))
       {
           ///get the login colum datetime
           /// add random datetime to it
           if (!dr.IsNull("login_time"))
           {
               DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["login_time"]);
               dt = dt.AddMinutes(?);/// "?"<--here I want to add random minutes
           }            
       }
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

> **Thank you all for the help, here my final Code snippet:**

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
       ///check if column[logout] is null or empty, fill it
       if(dr.IsNull("logout_time"))
       {
           ///get the login colum datetime
           /// add random datetime to it
           if (!dr.IsNull("login_time"))
           {
               DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["login_time"]);
               Random rand = new Random();
               //return random.Next(0, 59);
               dt = dt.AddMinutes(rand.Next(0,59));
               dt = dt.AddSeconds(rand.Next(0, 59));
               dr["logout_time"] = dt;

           }

       }
    }
```

Comment: * * * As noted by many below, it is essential to place the `Random rand = new Random()` line outside of your foreach loop. Otherwise, you will likely get a minutes sequence like `(42, 42, 42, 27, 27...)`, as Random is seeded by system time.

Comment: Also, the `rand.Next(0, 59)` statements should be `rand.Next(0, 60)` since the upper bound of `Random.Next()` is exclusive.  This will give you the desired `0-59` range.  Otherwise, looks good!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Random random = new Random();

foreach(DataRow dr ...)
{
   int rand = random.Next(0, 60); 
}
```

As a comment pointed out, you don't need to create a new Random object for every number you wish to create.  (Actually, you probably shouldn't).

Comment: Hmm. Creating a new Random every call? Not a good idea, as under stress it may well end up with the same seed twice. Not so random.

Comment: Kevin doesn't specify whether it's inside or outside the `foreach` ...give the man a break!

Comment: Sure, but worth reinforcing nonetheless

Comment: Upper bound for `Random.Next` is exclusive, so to get a number from 0 to 59 the call should be `random.Next(0, 60)`

Comment: actually shouldn't it be -1 to 60?

Comment: @Kevin - no, `random.Next(0, 60)` is correct. The lower-bound is inclusive, the upper-bound is exclusive

Comment: Sometimes we forget here on Stackoverflow that we are writing snippets to show how something is done.  Not production code.  Sometimes items are left out for brevity.

Comment: David, it's highly likely that person asking the question may use the code in production environment. [Obviously, they don't know the topic well otherwise they wouldn't ask the question] So it's important to note the subtle aspects of the code to educate the OP.

Comment: Although I agree the post should be complete, I think there is also is some onus on the person asking the question.  Once pointed in the right direction that person should look at the code and figure out what it is doing.  I can't think of a time ever when I wouldn't review code that I found on a website regardless of where.

Answer (score 7):

Try using `Random`:

```
Random randGen = new Random();

foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   ///check if column[logout] is null or empty, fill it
   if(dr.IsNull("logout_time"))
   {
       ///get the login colum datetime
       /// add random datetime to it
       if (!dr.IsNull("login_time"))
       {
           DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["login_time"]);
           dt = dt.AddMinutes(randGen.Next(0, 60));
           /// "?"<--here I want to add random minutes
       }            
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... think it's the same as Kevin's though ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Upper bound for `Random.Next` is exclusive, so to get a number from 0 to 59 the call should be `random.Next(0, 60)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want your dt object to get moved into the next hour (e.g., you would want any time between 8:00 and 8:59 to get moved up to 8:59 at most), I would suggest making the following changes:

```
protected void btnUpdateTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Random rand = new Random;

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
       ///check if column[logout] is null or empty, fill it
       if(dr.IsNull("logout_time"))
       {
           ///get the login colum datetime
           /// add random datetime to it
           if (!dr.IsNull("login_time"))
           {
               DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["login_time"]);
               dt = dt.AddMinutes(rand.Next(0, (60 - dt.Minutes)));
           }            
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a thoughtful addition... I wish the question was a bit more specific!

Answer (score 0):

Also please note that two if-statements within each other can be optimized to:

```
protected void btnUpdateTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
       if(dr.IsNull("logout_time") && !dr.IsNull("login_time")) {
          DateTime loginTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["login_time"]);
          loginTime = loginTime.AddMinutes(new Random().Next(0,59));
       }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `new Random()` in a loop like this, or you'll seed it with the same millisecond value continually producing the same number for about 10-20 iterations

Comment: An example in C# 3.0: `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i => new Random().Next()).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: thanks for the help, did not want to use "and" condition every time