# C# : How to generate unique passwords with the length of 7 or 8 characters

Tags: c#

I need to repeated generate unique password many times, Ensure that every time the generated passwords are unique, Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there's a cheap way to ensure no duplicates in the generator while keeping the generated passwords unpredictable.  I think you'd have to just store every generated one, so you can check against them when you make a new one.

Comment: There is no point in having the 'unique' requirement.  Only that N consecutive ones aren't the same.  That's easy.

Comment: Thanks all,I found this http://ramanisandeep.wordpress.com/tag/generate-unique-string-and-numbers-in-c/ , I need to verify this way is feasible

Comment: Just a joke, but you could consider scraping https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm and giving credit to Steve Gibson (the creator). There's a lot that goes into ensuring that the passwords are unique and random. If you want to implement it yourself, he gives all the details. Just be sure you get *everything* right.

Comment: Can you explain why you require uniqueness? By never storing the password itself and storing a salted hash of the password as the password equivalent you can ensure that two users with the same password do not have the same password equivalent. (I assume the attack you are worried about is that two users determine that their passwords are the same by inspecting their password equivalents; if that's not the attack you're worried about please clarify.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is another method which generates cryptedRandom password and a thread safe...

```
    private string CryptedRandomString()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            int rand = 0;

            byte[] randomNumber = new byte[5];

            RNGCryptoServiceProvider Gen = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            Gen.GetBytes(randomNumber);

            rand = Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(randomNumber, 0));

            return ConvertIntToStr(rand);
        }
    }

    private string ConvertIntToStr(int input)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            string output = "";
            while (input > 0)
            {
                int current = input % 10;
                input /= 10;

                if (current == 0)
                    current = 10;

                output = (char)((char)'A' + (current - 1)) + output;
            }
            return output;
        }

    }
```

Now you can call this method like this: -

```
string GeneratedPassword = "";

GeneratedPassword = CryptedRandomString() + CryptedRandomString();

Console.WriteLine(GeneratedPassword.Substring(0,8));
```

Now you all must be wondering why `GeneratedPassword = CryptedRandomString() + CryptedRandomString();` , the reason I called CryptedRamdomString() method twice is just to make sure it returns more then 10 digits so as it will be easier to get eight character passwords otherwise if it is called once then sometimes it will generate less then eight character password.

Well you must consider one thing before using this method that generating random numbers using "RNGCryptoServiceProvider " is bit time consuming then Random.Next. But "RNGCryptoServiceProvider " is much more secure then "Random.Next" .

Comment: thank you, i will try it later,I noticed you are using RNGCryptoServiceProvider,i think your way should better.

Comment: Just tested this by generating a set of 63,000 passwords. In that there were 51 duplicates. The first ones being at positions 133 and 134 the next at 779 and 780. Possibly not an ideal method for unique passwords without some more checking on the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate uniq password every time than

take CurrentTIME and CurrrentDATE in account because by this you can able to create new password.

have look to this resolve your problem : [generating a batch of random passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814576/generating-a-batch-of-random-passwords)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/3/15/c-pronounceable-password-generator.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd define an array of possible characters for the password alphabet, and then generate 7 or 8 random indexes into that array to create a password.

This would need to be refined if you want to guarantee a minimum number of each character type, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Globally unique strings you say?

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

Comment: Aye that it does.  Looks like OP will have to keep track of all passwords to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Kinda important that a human can memorize it.  If they can't then they'll write it down on a post-it note and stick it to the monitor.

Comment: Depends on the use case really.  If it is for machine use then GUID.  If it is for a human to enter then the character restriction should be much much higher than 8 characters as the best passwords are not single words.  Something like "My dog eats jellybeans for breakfast!" is easily remembered and not so easily hacked.

Comment: @Adam, in practice, and depending on the particular use case, it is not necessary to keep track of all password issued to ensure uniqueness. For example with only 36 characters (all letters, case insensitive, and all digits), there are in excess of 70 millions of unique strings of 7 such characters, and about 2.8 billions with 8 characters.  Assuming the total number of password issued is relatively small, and assuming the RNG is properly managed, it is statistically safe to assume there will be no collisions.

Comment: @mjv: Just how statistically safe is safe?  For the 7 character strings drawn from a 36 character set the probability of there being at least one collision exceeds 1% after only a few thousand generated. Remember, the set size has to be small relative to the *square root* of the size of the space, not small relative to the entire size of the space!

Comment: @Eric: `Thank you` for catching my mistake! I was way off... Indeed a 7-long or even an 8-long string from a 36 characters alphabet spans too small a space to ensure we wouldn't get _at least_ one collision within a few thousand attempts. Aside from the square root rule of thumb you mention and the applications of the Bernoulli trials, we can demonstrate that you are right with the following...

Comment: The probability of _not_ having a collision on the very 5001st drawing alone is P = 1 - (5000/70000000) or approximately 0.9999285714285714.  This probability diminishes to 1 - (6000/70000000) for the 6001st drawing but assuming it remains the same between of the 5001st and the 6001st drawings,  the probability of not having a collision within say 150 drawings in this range, it less than 0.9999285714285714 ^ 150 = 0.98935   meaning that there'd be more than a 1% chance of this happening...  far from my "statistically safe" optimist statement :-(